# Firefox jumpiness involving CSS scale and canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, css-transforms

In Firefox (121.0b9), when scaling canvas elements, I notice slight jitteriness. I don't experience this in Safari or Chromium. Is there a way to work around this in Firefox?

Here's an example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jos4vbc1/)). (If you're on macOS, activate "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom" to zoom in on the bottom right corner. On JSFiddle, when you're zoomed in, use "Command + Enter" to rerun.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
  canvas {
    margin: 100px;
  }
</style>

<canvas width="400" height="400" />

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    // make canvas
    const elem = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const ctx = elem.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 300, 300);

    // scale loop
    const start = performance.now();
    const end = start + 2000;

    const tick = () => {
      const now = performance.now();
      const t = Math.min(1, (now - start) / (end - start));
      const t2 = 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t); // easeOutExpo
      elem.style.transform = `scale(${1 - 0.5 * t2})`;
      if (now < end) {
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
      }
    };

    tick();
  };
</script>
```

Possibly related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663776

Answer (score 1):

here is a different approach, you could use delta time instead

```
const tick = (timestamp) => {
        if (!start) {
            start = timestamp || performance.now();
        }
        const elapsed = (timestamp || performance.now()) - start;
        const t = Math.min(1, elapsed / (end - start));
        const t2 = parseFloat(1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t).toFixed(3)) + 0.0002;
        elem.style.transform = `scale(${1 - (0.5 * parseFloat(t2.toFixed(3)))})`;
        if (elapsed < end - start) {
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

## Demo

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/g3etx9b1/)

## Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
  canvas {
    margin: 100px;
  }
</style>

<canvas width="400" height="400" />

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    // make canvas
    const elem = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const ctx = elem.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 300, 300);

    // scale loop
    const start = parseFloat(performance.now().toFixed(3));
    const end = start + 2000;

    const tick = (timestamp) => {
        if (!start) {
            start = timestamp || performance.now();
        }
        const elapsed = (timestamp || performance.now()) - start;
        const t = Math.min(1, elapsed / (end - start));
        const t2 = parseFloat(1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t).toFixed(3)) + 0.0002;
        elem.style.transform = `scale(${1 - (0.5 * parseFloat(t2.toFixed(3)))})`;
        if (elapsed < end - start) {
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @Michael I've updated my answer with a new appoarch (still using my old code) but now with support for firefox

Comment: I appreciate the fast responses. I tried your old and your new version (as of 2023-12-15 12:58:29Z) and both have shakiness for me in Firefox (121.0b9).